# How to I make a div have the same style's as anther but with a different name?

Tags: css, html, styles

I'm basically stuck in a situation where I need a bunch of div's with the same style (height, width, opacity, etc) but I need them all to have different names (test1, test2, test3, etc.) is there any way to easily set the style of one div to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give them both a class and an id like so:

```
<div id="test1" class="divstyle">
</div>
<div id="test2" class="divstyle">
</div>
<div id="test3" class="divstyle">
</div>     

<style>
  .divstyle{
    color:red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`class`](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/):

```
<style>
div.mystyle {
    width: 10px;
}
</style>
<div class="mystyle" id="test1"/>
<div class="mystyle" id="test2"/>
<div class="mystyle" id="test3"/>
<div class="mystyle" id="test4"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this **common** practice of **cascading** css.

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="common diff01"></div>
<div class="common diff02"></div>
<div class="common diff03"></div>
<div class="common diff04"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* sizes and colors are demo only */
.common {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.diff01 { background-color: #FFF; }
.diff02 { background-color: #AAA; }
.diff03 { background-color: #333; }
.diff04 { background-color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
#test1, #test2, #test3, #test4 { font-size:13px; }
```

All those ID's will share that style, just use a comma to separate the IDs.